# PaintCode 2 vs 3 incompatible due to resizableImageWithCapInsets

Tags: paintcode

I recently switched from using PaintCode 2 to PaintCode 3, I am using it together with xCode/Swift.

I noticed however, that all my image generating functions not behave differently. They seam to standard addopt cap insets.

As an example below you can find one canvas "ViewMissingImage", and how its configured in PaintCode (2 or 3 its identical).

[image]

Code generated via PaintCode 2

```
public class func imageOfViewMissingImage(frame frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 6, y: 5, width: 109, height: 109)) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, false, 0)
        PaintCode.drawViewMissingImage(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))

    let imageOfViewMissingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return imageOfViewMissingImage
}
```

Code generated via PaintCode 3

```
public dynamic class func imageOfViewMissingImage(imageSize imageSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 109, height: 109)) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 0)
        PaintCode.drawViewMissingImage(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))

    let imageOfViewMissingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero, resizingMode: .Tile)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return imageOfViewMissingImage
}
```

I think that the PaintCode 2 never used the capp insets, maybe it was a bug?
I do not want these cap insets, how can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is straightforward:

Put the Cap Inset on "Stretch" instead of tile in PaintCode UI!